# How to define the Heaviside function in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

Commonly, in the mathematical literature, the Heaviside function it is not simply refereed as H(t-theta). The letter H is drawn with a different letter. My question is: How to define the Heaviside function in LaTeX?

While I was looking the answer I found that:

The H of Heaviside function can be drawn as

```
$\mathcal{H}$.
```

Comment: @ana brásio: Can you give an example where it is printed?

Comment: The question states that the answer is `\mathcal H`. So what is the point?

Comment: The OP seems to have found its answer by itself and didn't returned to stackoverflow (where the question was originally asked) every since. I'm closing the question because of that.

Comment: @Martin: Could as well be deleted in my opinion.

Comment: @Hendrik: I'd leave it open in case the OP returns.

Comment: @Caramdir: Well, over at SO it's an _unregistered_ user, last seen when _posting this very question_ ...

Comment: Can we please reopen this question??? It's answered by anyone providing a few different ways of writing the heaviside function. It's asking for suggestions. Let's be helpful and provide a few (to me, and to others).